# Ajax script not working properly

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, html, jquery

I am new to ajax

I have this script and I wanted to know what it does... in big lines I have figured it out but it's still not working.

Here goes the script:

```
function calcPrice(elem,id,pret,i){

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "ajaxHandler.php",
   data: "action=calcPrice&sign="+elem.className+"&id="+id+"&pret="+pret,
   success: function(msg){
    hcont = get_response_tag('tag1',msg);
    hcont2 = get_response_tag('tag2',msg);
     $(".price_val").html(hcont);  
     $(".nb_analize").html(hcont2);  

    if(elem.className=='plus'){ $("#p_row_"+i).removeClass("row_plus").addClass("row_minus"); elem.className = 'minus'; }
    else{  $("#p_row_"+i).removeClass("row_minus").addClass("row_plus"); elem.className = 'plus'; }
   }
});

}
```

Should I have something written in `ajaxHandler.php` for this script to work?

The html looks like this... (part of it)

```
<div id="p_row_10" class="tableRow4 ">
    <div class="tableRow4_leftBg float-left">10</div>
    <div class="tableRow4_middleBg2 float-left">Ac. anti adenovirus</div>
    <div class="tableRow4_middleBg3 float-left">73.00</div>
    <div class="tableRow4_middleBg4 float-left">
        <div class="plus" onclick="calcPrice(this,36,73.00,10)"></div>
    </div>
</div>   

<div id="p_row_11" class="tableRow4 ">
    <div class="tableRow4_leftBg float-left">11</div>
    <div class="tableRow4_middleBg2 float-left">Ac. anti ADN dublu catenar </div>
    <div class="tableRow4_middleBg3 float-left">79.00</div>
    <div class="tableRow4_middleBg4 float-left">
        <div class="plus" onclick="calcPrice(this,37,79.00,11)"></div>
    </div>
</div>   


<div align="right">
    <div class="cp_pret" >
        <div class="t">TOTAL</div>
        <div class="p"><span class="price_val">0</span> LEI</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Not working means? what error do you see in `console`?

Comment: What does the debug tool of your choice say (p.e. firebug), when the function `calcPrice` is fired?

Comment: Add this `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){}` to your ajax block. Error message may help

Comment: Have you called the function?

Comment: `error` is deprecated. Please use `fail()` instead.

Comment: THANK YOU ALL FOR ANSWERING. what this does... i have a list of items with various prices... i want to be able when i click on plus sign to add the sum to a TOTAL box and when i click on that plus it will automatically turn into a minus. when i click again on that minus, it will automatically subtract that sum. the changing happens but the sum does not appear in TOTAL field.

Comment: No errors on firebug...

Comment: "GET http://localhost/calc/ajaxHendler.php?action=calcPrice&sign=plus&id=37&pret=79"
 
this is what i get in firebug when i click on + sign... but still in TOTAL nothing appears... the 0 disappears but no sum in TOTAL... What can i do?

Answer (score 0):

ajaxHandler.php is necessary for this ajax request to work. If there is no ajaxHandler.php file, there will be 404 error. Also, output produced by ajaxHandler.php is held by msg variable in success function of ajax request.

Comment: The data structure doesn't make any difference. Jquery will serialize it before the call.

Comment: so... there must be something written in ajaxHandler.php for this to work... right?

Comment: Yes, of course. Without ajaxHandler.php your ajax request will fail, and success method in ajax request will not work.

Comment: Until now i have figured out that i should have something like this...
    echo'<tag1>'; some code; echo'</tag1><tag2>'; some other code; echo'</tag2>';

Comment: I don't know what ajaxHandler does, but it takes some parameters from ajax via POST. You can see these parameters in data field of ajax request (action,id,pret). After getting these parameters in ajaxHandler.php  and doing some works on it (based on what you want it to do), you must send the output from php to javascript (e.g. using echo).